# What's the proper way to bond metallic signal wiring raceway?

Tags: conduit, low-voltage, grounding-and-bonding

I have a stud cavity through which I need to run some signal wiring that's sensitive to ingress noise. [An industry-standard recommendation](https://www.cepro.com/article/understanding_fixing_hdmi_noise) is to run the wiring in properly bonded metal conduit (raceway, per the NEC, right?).

There are plenty of 110V metal junction boxes in the same stud cavity. However, I can't mix signal and control wiring in the same junction box (or compartment of the junction box) with 110V wiring. Nor can I put it in the same raceway, right?

Supposing that I run new RMC and metal junction boxes for the signal wiring, how should I bond the boxes (or at least one box if the RMC provides electrical continuity to the other)? Do I use a bonding jumper from the signal wire box to one of the 110V boxes?

[image: bonding jumper]

The signal wires are going to be electrically isolated from the boxes (i.e. they pass through brush plates and aren't terminated at the boxes).

Comment: Can you run a ground wire to the same ground system that the electric service uses?  In a house, the phone and cable TV wires are commonly grounded to the electric service either by a clamp on the meter box or directly to the main grounding conductor.

Comment: Since you're doing this for noise immunity rather than safety, I recommend you ground the entire run from exactly one point, to avoid making ground loops or having any current flow on your ground.  Agreed with @JPhi1618 that you want to ground it to the electrical system, ideally as close to the service panel as possible.

Comment: @JPhi1618 The main service ground is a long way away--perhaps 100 ft or more.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to go full RMC; cheaper EMT and plain stamped handy-boxes will do.  Both types of conduit are acceptable as grounding paths for 200A++ of fault current, your milliamps of signal noise will be handled with ease.  I never run ground wires inside EMT.

If you have a section of Conduit isolated from mains grounding, grounding it is simplicity itself.  There should be a hole in the back of the box tapped #10-32.  You simply put a 10-32 screw in there, shepherd's hook a 12AWG solid pigtail to it, and wirenut that to your grounding wire, any color you like as long as it's green, yellow/green or bare.

Then you exit the wire through a cable clamp or grommet, which fits in a standard knockout.

Then you run the wire in-wall to whichever ground point you deem appropriate.  If you'd like guidance on that, look at the NEC rules for retrofitting ground.

Comment: When I'm running the ground wire to whichever ground point I deem appropriate, does it need to be in some sort of raceway or jacket (i.e. NM with a single conductor)? I ask because all the cable clamps I've seen are meant to be used with NM cable--not just a single conductor.

Comment: @watkipet -- grounding wires can be run by themselves as long as they are not subject to physical damage; if you or your inspector insist on a cable though, then an 8/1 Bare Armored Ground cable can be used for this.

Comment: It's true, cable clamps are not well suited to single wires.  Not a lot of good answers.  You could wrap it with electrical tape enough to fatten it up.